# Redux splitting reducers - export several in one file

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, es6-modules

I'm trying to get a state shape like this:

```
state = {
  items: {
    currentItem: object,
    byId: object,
    allIds: array,
    fetching: bool
  },
  someOtherModule = { ... }
}
```

I've split my items reducers into two files, trying to not have everything in one file; note that this is just pseudocode to illustrate what I'm doing -

**items/reducers/currentItem.js**

```
const currentItem = (state = null, action) => ...
export default currentItem;
```

I've tried it this way:

**items/reducers/items.js**

```
const byId = (state = {}, action) => ...
const allIds = (state = [], action) => ...
const fetching = (state = false, action) => ...
export default {byId, allIds, fetching};
```

**items/reducers/index.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import item from './item';
import currentItem from './currentItem';

export default combineReducers({ item, currentItem });
```

And I've tried it this way:

**items/reducers/items.js**

```
export const byId = (state = {}, action) => ...
export const allIds = (state = [], action) => ...
export const fetching = (state = false, action) => ...
```

**items/reducers/index.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import * as item from './item';
import currentItem from './currentItem';

export default combineReducers({ item, currentItem });
```

And I end up with a "root items reducer" that only has currentItem, no "items".

If I export `combineReducers({byId, allIds, fetching})` in items.js it works, but it adds a level to my state:

```
state = {
      items: {
        currentItem: object,
        items: { 
         byId: object,
         allIds: array,
         fetching: bool
        }
      },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out; combineReducers expects an object that's keys are the reducer names and values are reducers functions (TLDR - read the manual):

**items/reducers/items.js**

```
export const byId = (state = {}, action) => ...
export const allIds = (state = [], action) => ...
export const fetching = (state = false, action) => ...
```

**items/reducers/index.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { byId, allIds, fetching } as item from './item';
import currentItem from './currentItem';

export default combineReducers({ byId, allIds, fetching, currentItem });
```

I think I'll put everything back into one file, it is simpler this way.

Comment: doing `export default combineReducers({ ...item, currentItem });` on the question version should get you there

Comment: @enapupe - Nice!